# My internal hard drive only appears in the windows operating system

Tags: boot, multi-boot, operating-systems, bootable-media

Does anyone have an idea why my disk only appears in windows.

I have tried to install kali linux, wifislax, chrome flux and many other systems, but the problem is that the internal disk of the device does not appear when I try to install any of the systems.

The only system that shows the disk is my default system (windows 10)

Do you have an idea what is going on with me?

Comment: We need more details: What make and model is the drive and your mainboard, how are the two connected, are there other drives that show up, how/from which drive are you booting Windows, how did you determine it doesn’t show up in Linux (installer, `fdisk`, …), how are you booting Linux?

Comment: Yes, there are a few hypotheses but the more likely is Intel RST, still not supported in most distros (and certainly not expected to be supported in Kali Linux which ISN'T a normal desktop Linux distro...)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think that the problem is not in the systems but in the bios, because I tried more than 5 operating systems and the disk did not appear for me. My device is dell latitude 3410

Comment: @daniel-b When installing any system, it does not show me any disk other than the flash disk. All this happens in systems other than Windows

Comment: Dell Latitude 3410 is [certified with Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/certified?q=latitude+3410). Have you replaced the hard disk? If in the BIOS the disk is in IDE mode, change this to AHCI mode. After such a change Windows will not boot, unless you do it [this way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696413/ubuntu-installer-cant-find-any-disk-on-dell-xps-13-9350).

Comment: It worked, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dell Latitude 3410 is
[certified with Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/certified?q=latitude+3410).

You should in the BIOS ensure that the disk is in IDE mode.
If not, change this to AHCI mode.
Note that after such a change, Windows will not boot, any more.

If you wish to keep Windows a bootable, follow
[this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696413/ubuntu-installer-cant-find-any-disk-on-dell-xps-13-9350).